# how to solve django.core.exceptions.FieldError?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have 3 models

```
class Car(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Driver, on_delete=None)
    car_type = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=car_type_choices)

class Ride(models.Model):
    pickup_time = models.IntegerField()
    dropoff_time = models.IntegerField()
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Payment(models.Model):
    ride = models.ForeignKey(Ride, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.FloatField()
```

and i have to write a query with 3 conditions:

1. if car_type is A, do A`
2. if car_type is B, do B`
3. if car_type is C, do C`

I write the query but get this exception: **django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Expression contains mixed types. You must set output_field.**

also when i comment first and second conditions, third works and when i just comment third one, first and second works **but all at the same time does not works.**

```py
q = Car.objects.annotate(
    extras=Case(
        When(car_type='A', then=Count('ride')),
        When(car_type='B', then=Sum(F('ride__dropoff_time') - F('ride__pickup_time'), output_field=FloatField())),
        When(car_type='C', then=Sum(F('ride__payment__amount'), output_field=FloatField()))
    )
)
```

Comment: Did you try setting `output_field` for the first query?

Comment: yes but it did not work. i don't know what is happening when i run all of them :|

Comment: type of first and second query results are number (int) and third is money (float). i think the reason for the error is this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide output_field for all cases and wrap individual expressions inside `Value` as explained in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case). So query would be:

```
from django.db.models import Value

q = Car.objects.annotate(
    extras=Case(
        When(car_type='A', then=Value(Count('ride'))),
        When(car_type='B', then=Value(Sum(F('ride__dropoff_time') - F('ride__pickup_time'))),
        When(car_type='C', then=Value(Sum(F('ride__payment__amount'))),
        output_field=FloatField()
    )
)
```